# Intellij IDEA 2017.1.5 connection times out during plugin installation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-15

I have a problem with my IDE. It does not want to neither update or install any plugins (but it allows me to register my licence and browse through every plugin). It gives me a notification:

> Connection failed (Read timed out). Please check network connection and try again

I looked into a log file and here what's there is:

```
> 2017-07-12 19:32:41,687 [ 653407]   INFO -
> .script.IdeScriptEngineManager - javax.script.ScriptEngineManager
> initialized in 2327 ms  2017-07-12 19:33:50,610 [ 722330]   WARN -
> Settings.impl.PluginDownloader - Cannot download
> 'https://plugins.jetbrains.com/pluginManager/?action=download&id=Lombook+Plugin&build=IU-171.4694.70&uuid=52f34c2e-c3bf-400b-a1c7-d11cc4fdb02b':
> Read timed out  java.io.IOException: Cannot download
> 'https://plugins.jetbrains.com/pluginManager/?action=download&id=Lombook+Plugin&build=IU-171.4694.70&uuid=52f34c2e-c3bf-400b-a1c7-d11cc4fdb02b':
> Read timed out    at
> com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.saveToFile(HttpRequests.java:363)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.PluginDownloader$1.process(PluginDownloader.java:245)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.PluginDownloader$1.process(PluginDownloader.java:242)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.lambda$doProcess$0(HttpRequests.java:420)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager.runWithUntrustedCertificateStrategy(CertificateManager.java:349)
>   at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:420)
>   at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:395)
>   at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:61)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:263)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.PluginDownloader.a(PluginDownloader.java:242)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.PluginDownloader.prepareToInstall(PluginDownloader.java:142)
>   at
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginInstaller.a(PluginInstaller.java:239)
>   at
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginInstaller.a(PluginInstaller.java:131)
>   at
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginInstaller.prepareToInstall(PluginInstaller.java:70)
>   at
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerMain$5.run(PluginManagerMain.java:431)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
>   at
> com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out   at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)     at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)     at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)   at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)   at
> sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)  at
> sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)   at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)     at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
>   at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)    at
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)    at
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)   at
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)    at
> sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)  at
> sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)    at
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536)
>   at
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
>   at
> java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
>   at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.openConnection(HttpRequests.java:511)
>   at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$300(HttpRequests.java:61)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getConnection(HttpRequests.java:289)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getInputStream(HttpRequests.java:298)
>   at
> com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.saveToFile(HttpRequests.java:359)
>   ... 27 more
```

Does anyone encounter similar problem and know how to solve it?

Comment: See if [disabling this option](http://i.imgur.com/p037pW2.png) helps. Also try adding `-Didea.connection.timeout=90000` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options.

Comment: Disabling that option helped. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>Posting [CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder)'s comment as answer, because it also worked for me.</sup>

---

Workaround is to uncheck ***Use secure connection*** option in *Appearance & Behavior → System Settings → Updates* section in *Settings* window:

[image: 'Appearance & Behavior → System Settings → Updates' section screenshot]

Comment: The secure connection option is not available in the latest intellij idea v2019.3.1. But the error did not occur after restarting the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same problem in IntelliJ 2020.3. Turned out IntelliJ's default proxy setting is "No proxy". I set it to auto-detect and the problem was solved. If you're behind a firewall (e.g. corporate environment), check this.

Answer (score 0):

Settings--Apperance & Behavior--System Settings--Updates--Use secure connection(make it unchecked)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVURF.png)